# I don't understand how my compiler got this output

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Note that I am using a Turbo C++ compiler because we are supposed to learn only Turbo C++ for our school syllabus. Which is why, the `cout` statement is evaluated from right to left in this case.

**Program**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *s, char t[]) {
    strcpy(t, "Have fun");
    s = "Be\0Cool";
    cout << s[0] << ++s << s++ << --s << strupr(s+2) << ++s << s++ << s;
}

int main() {
    char x[] = "Hello World!!!", y[] = "Hello World";
    func(x, y);
    cout << x << y;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> CCOOLeeOOLBeBeHello World!!!Have fun

---

I feel the output should be:

> C**Cool**eeOOLBeBeHello World!!!Have fun

Because in the `++s` part of the `cout` statement (second position), the pointer is at index **3** of the string `s`, so only 'Cool' should be printed. Instead 'COOL' is being printed. Why does this happen?

Comment: Undefined behavior and the fact that `strupr` convert a whole string.

Comment: `because we are supposed to learn only Turbo C++ for our school syllabus` That's too bad.

Comment: "Turbo C++" == "a waste of your time". That compiler is *never* going to be relevant in your life going forward and the (not C++) language that it teaches you is something you are going to have to un-learn. Don't waste your time on that obsolete crap..

Comment: @Phil1970 But strupr() shouldn't change the string as it is only in the cout statement. Moreover, if it converted the whole string, shouldn't it print 'EE' rather than 'ee'

Comment: Don't worry @JesperJuhl I'm learning the new version as well. But can't help it, have to learn this too for school

Comment: You should never modify the same variable (here `s`) in a single expression more than once because the order of evaluation is not specified (or was specified (for some cases) long after Turbo C++ was made). Also, it make the code hard to understand. Better to use multiple statements and maybe add a few comments...

Comment: @Sujit  It *does* change the string. It doesn't magically make space somewhere in the ether, convert to upper case and store in that space, then return a pointer to said-same. The ensuing memory leak would be hideous. It converts in-place. The resulting `char*` returned is a convenience for use in expressions. Regardless, that `cout` chain invokes UB, plain and simple.

Comment: Hey @WhozCraig I think you are on to something. Does it change the second part of that string as it is a pointer? Can you explain it properly in an answer?

Comment: @Sujit It does not make any sense to write such code that depends on **undefined behavior** and even less sense to try to understand it. **Write correct code using multiple statements.**

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is the last year of Turbo C++ (Thankfully) from next year it's Python 3.x. Sadly I'll be finishing school this year so I won't get a chance to learn Python at school.

Comment: @Phil1970 These are the kinds of questions that are asked in our exams. They ask us to write the output of programs like this one to improve our understanding of C++. Also, could you please tell me exactly what **Undefined Behavior** actually means. It will be helpful for me and I can ask better questions on SO in future.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @Sujit https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: In modern C++ undefined behavior is when the C++ standard (which specifies exactly how the C++ language works) doesn't define the behavior of your program which means any behavior is possible. The C++ standard didn't exist yet at the time of Turbo-C++, but you get the idea. So if the question doesn't have "undefined behavior" as an answer choice then it is plain wrong. Unfortunately I don't know of any way to deal with bullcrap like this taught in schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tests with Visual Studio 2019**

For comparison purpose, in Visual Studio 2019 (DEBUG), if we make required change to compile the code, then the program crash because we try to modify a constant string (`"Be\0Cool"`).

If we do additional change to avoid the crash (by using a local array), the output is:

> CCoOLeCoOLOLCoOLBeCoOLHello World!!!Have fun

If we split `cout << s[]…;` line to multiple calls to `cout` (one before each `<<`), then the output would be:

> BeeeCOOLCOOLHello World!!!Have fun

Or if we add a line after each output, we get:

```
B
e
e
e
COOL


COOL
Hello World!!!
Have fun
```

**Trying to understand the output of Turbo C++**

If we then reverse each call to cout to start with the last (i.e. `cout << s<< endl;`) and end with first (`cout << s[0] << endl`), then we get:

```
Be
Be

OOL
e
e
COOL
C
Hello World!!!
Have fun
```

If we manually write that starting with the third last line and up and then the two last line in order without space, we get:

> CCOOLeeOOLBeBeHello World!!!Have fun

Which is exactly what you got as an output.

Thus, it appears that Turbo C++ evaluate every expression from the right to the left.

**Notes about required changes to compile (and run)**

- `<iostream.h>` is not available so I have to use `<iostream>` instead.
- `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` must be added at top because some functions are not secure (and won't compile by default).
- `using namespace std;` to avoid making more change to the code.
- Add cast in `s = (char *)"Be\0Cool";`  so that line compile.

  - This lead to a crash because data is constant and we try to modify it.
- Remove the cast and instead write `char data[] = "Be\0Cool"; s = data;`

  - The program run but the output is `CCoOLeCoOLOLCoOLBeCoOLHello World!!!Have fun`
  - In fact, this is undefined behavior. It just happen to be the actual output.

**Undefined behavior**

Some things are not defined by the standard and thus are not required to work a certain way. Well, as expected if read-only memory is not supported, it works like read-write memory.

For the order of evaluation, common possibilities are:

- left to right
- right to left
- whatever is more optimal

Also since a variable is modified more than once, the value of s is not defined during the evaluation and afterward. The easy to remember rule is to avoid modifying the same variable more than once in a single expression.

**About strupr**

That function modify the string up to the terminating null character. In your case, it would convert to uppercase every letters from whatever value `s` has at the moment of the call.